# HTML Code to put image in left and text in right side of screen with footer below?

Tags: html

This is what my page should look like -

```
--------Header (will put code to load header from external site here)
--Image on left side - Text on right side.
--------Footer ((will put code to load footer from external site here))
```

How can I do this? I am actually looking for a template where all I have to do is place my image, text and header and footer code.

Comment: Should the text wrap around the image or should they be two distinct columns?

Comment: @2C-B - the text should be on the right side of the image, ie two distinct columns. Anyway, i dont know what wrap around means.

Comment: Can we do this without CSS ? I never did CSS before. I am not doing a web dev job, just want a page, quick, simple and easy.

Comment: Without CSS you would have to use tables. Everything else must be styled with CSS. In fact, CSS is great, you should go learn it. :)

Comment: @MrXenotype - can i put css in my html code ?

Comment: Yes, CSS is practically integrated into HTML. CSS(Cascading Style Sheets) allows coders to have more control over styling elements in HTML. If you follow 2C-B's answer down below, just put the CSS in `<style></style>` tags in the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: Look at this page for some guidance: http://w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1:**

For text wrapping around the image, use this basic HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  ... contents go here ...
</div>

<div id="content">
  <img src="sample.jpg" alt="" />
  <p>Example content</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  ... contents go here ...
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#content img {
  float: left;
}
```

**Option 2:**

For two distinct content columns, use this HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  ... contents go here ...
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="sample.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Example content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  ... contents go here ...
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#content .col {
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: what is this css ? does it work if put inside an HTML page ?

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp Perhaps work through some of the tutorials. It will provide you with a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr> 
    <td colspan="2">
    HEADER HERE
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 70%">IMAGE</td> <-Change these to respective widths
    <td style="width: 30%">TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td colspan="2">
    FOOTER HERE
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout!

Comment: Tables are perfectly fine to be used for layout. I find them easy to use and easy to configure.

Comment: Tables are not perfectly fine for layout. Tables are by specification intended for tabular data only. There are many other tags that are more suitable for layout. Also, using tables for layout is detrimental to web accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tables.
Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2sWrF/1/

You use css to float the image and text so they are side by side

the `.cf` in the css is a clearfix it makes it so that the footer will go underneath the div with the image and text instead of being to the side of it

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use responsive layout http://jsfiddle.net/PSBtr/12/
Iframe as a ebbedded page.

```
iframe
```

Adoptive grid as a markup.